# Javascript fast variable not exists alternative

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm looking for a fast way to check a boolean variable without check if it exists, for example:

```
if(variable){
   alert(variable);
}
```

But here I may get "ReferenceError: variableis not defined"

Comment: How can a variable not exist in working code? (unless you are including multiple different sources maybe)

Comment: Actually, there's no such thing as a "variable that doesn't exist" in javascript. Variables always do exist. You're probably asking about a "global variable" which is a property of the `window` object, in which case you're looking for `if(name in window)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typeof` to check if the variable exists or not.

```
if((typeof variable !== "undefined") && variable) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(typeof variable != 'undefined'){
   alert(variable);
}
```